# how can i find com.ibm.ejs.perf classes in which jar

Tags: java, class, build, websphere

we want to build   com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar.

and we met error:

java: package com.ibm.ws390.recoverylog.spi not exists.

but we dont know such classes in which jar .

`com.ibm.ejs.perf.*,com.ibm.ws390.recoverylog.* .`

we have unziped  all jars in was ,rad,and ibm bpm ,but can not find them.

so can u tell us the jar names which contains such classes ?

or can you offer us the jars ?

thank you in advance .
error :

`java: package com.ibm.ws390.recoverylog.spi not exists.`

Answer (score 1):

You can't build the runtime.jar for WebSphere, your license entitles you to install and use it, not reverse engineer and rebuild it.